# "int" object not callable error, even tho I (guess) am using float

Tags: python, int

My code:

```
import math


def celsius(F):
    C= 5/9(F-32)
    return C

Fahr=float(input("Qual a temperatura em Fahrenheit? "))
Cels= celsius(Fahr)

print("A respetiva temperatura em Celsius é ",Cels)
```

It gives me the following error:

> int object is not callable

After the input line, what's wrong with it?

Comment: `C= 5/9(F-32)` — You need to use the multiplication operator `*` for multiplication.

Comment: oh, what a simple fix and stupid mistake, ty anyway, it fixed the issue xd

Answer (score 2):

The expression `C= 5/9(F-32)` is illegal, use `*` between the two multiplication arguments: `C = (5/9)*(F-32)`.